# How create a user interactive popup kind of form

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I am looking for something which comes up as a popup on click of a link or button but It must be more than just a popup. It must be a Interactive form which asks for inputs and when Inputs are provided it takes The input back to the parent window. I am not asking for the code. I just don't know which kind of technology it is. Do you know what I am Talking about?

Comment: can you use jQuery in you task, or need to do it with pure javascript?

Comment: I can use jquery. Is it possible with it ?

Comment: Please, do not for Chuck Norris's sake.. Popups are worse so annoying. Do anything else than that. Make a div appear like a modal dialog inside your web page.

Comment: @jabal I am asking the same thing what else can work like a Popups ? can you give me a link for this `modal dialog` I barely know what that is.

Answer (score 1):

1, Include jQuery into your HTML via `<script src=..>`
2, See this tutorial on how to create modal overlays via jQuery:

http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html

http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-modal-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, in the child window (popup) you can call your parent window (the opener) and target a field therein with something like this:

```
$("#fieldInParent", opener.window.document).val("new value");
```

opener.window.document tells jquery that the ID is in the window that opened the popup.

Comment: if you dont want to use jQuery, something like:

window.opener.getElementById('fieldInParent').innerHTML( "new value");

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest doing something like the following.
In JS:

```
$container = $("#container");
$("<div class=\"popup\" id=\"popup-id\"><!--html code of form here--><div>").hide().appendTo($container);
....
function showPopup() {
    $("#popup-id").show().offset({
    left : yourX,
    top : yourY
});

}
```

in HTML:

```
<!-- container of popup -->
<div id="container">
    ...
<div>
...
<a onclick="showPopup()">Show Pop Up</a>
```

in CSS

```
div.popup {
    display: inline-block 
}
```

That should work.

**UPD.** And even more. Instead of creating `div` with `$("<div class=\"popup\" id=\"popup-id\"><!--html code of form here--><div>")`. You can use `jquery.tmpl()` function.